# ObservableCollection<T> CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have an observable collection and I have a collectionChanged event wired up on that.
I have its items bound to a listbox in the UI.
When the user removes some items in the UI from the listbox, the CollectioChanged gets fired properly, however, I need to know the indices of the items that were removed.
The problem is I am not able to an indexOf on the collection after it is changed because it does not have the removed item anymore..

Can we get access to the list of indexes that were removed from an ObservableCollection from the collectionchanged event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event uses an event that gives you a [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.aspx). This has a `OldStartingIndex` property, which will tell you the index it was removed at. For example:

```
void Foo()
{
    ObservableCollection<string> r = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    r.CollectionChanged += r_CollectionChanged;
}

static void r_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemRemovedAtIndex = e.OldStartingIndex;
}
```

> Assume that I am removing MULTIPLE items from the collection at different indices..So using the oldStartingIndex would just give me the first item index that was removed

The event will most likely fire multiple times, once for each item.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.oldstartingindex.aspx

Comment: Yes, but if i have multiple items removed, then ?

Comment: I have only ONE old starting index...what if I removed items from index position 3, 6, or 9 as an example?

Comment: @user1202434 The event will fire multiple times, or if the items are contiguous, like 3, 4, 5, use `OldItems.Count` to determine the how many, starting from the "Starting Index". Something like `var manyIndexes = Enumerable.Range(e.OldStartingIndex, e.OldItems.Count);`

Comment: You can get them using e.OldItems ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `OldStartingIndex` in the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` is the index from which the item was removed.

Answer (score 1):

The event argument `e` has the properties `OldItems` and `OldStartingIndex`. May be this helps?

Comment: Yes, but if i have multiple items removed, then it wont. I need to know all the indices that were removed.

Comment: I see only the methods `Remove(item)`, `RemoveAt(index)` and `Clear()` in `ObservableCollection<T>`. How do you want to remove items at non-contiguous positions at once? You will probably have to remove them one by one and the `CollectionChanged` event will be called once for each single item removed. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that you can remove multiple items from an `ObservableCollection` with a single method call. This is not possible. You have to call either `Remove`, `RemoveAt`, or `RemoveItem` and all of these only remove a single element from the collection. This means that each time an item is removed from the collection, the remove event will fire and the `OldStartingIndex` and `OldItems` will contain a reference to the index of the one item that was removed and a single element array of the one item respectively.

You cannot do a lookup in the collection using the `OldStartingIndex` as you have noted because it has been removed. If you need access to the item that was original referenced there you can use `OldItems` and take the first element.

I have not used `ObservableCollection` but the only way I see to remove more than one element at a single time is to call `Clear` or `ClearItems`. If these fire a changed event then I would imagine that `OldStartingIndex` would be 0 and `OldItems` would contain a reference to all the elements that were previously in the collection.