# C# remove item from list will update database internally

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a programming scenario that I am currently looking into. I would like to remove items at the same time perform some special functions behind the scene that, in this case, will update an external database.

I thought about using an IDisposable but that would perform the deletion during shutdown of the program. If this is correct, is there some way to perform a clean-up operation only when I remove an item from a list, not during a program shutdown.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Per the comments, here is some example code:

```
public class CItem
{
    private string Name;
    private int Data;

    public void destroy()
    {
        // Do something that performs clean up only during run-time, not program exiting
    }
}
public class CMain
{
    private List<CItem> items;

    public setItem(CItem newItem)
    {
        items.add(newItem);
    }

    public removeFirstItem()
    {
        items.remove(items[0]);  // remove the first item and dispose
    }
}
```

The line items.remove(items[0]), is it possible that when an item is removed and destroyed, can I perform a back ground disposal that is only limited to the disposal during run-time?

Comment: first, make use of 'using' statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx. second, mind to share some code maybe?

Comment: This question is very confusing as to what you're trying to do, but one thing I think I can help with is that `IDisposable` does **NOT** get called on shutdown. You **MUST** explicitly call `.Dispose()` to dispose of all `IDisposable` objects.

Comment: Use a BindingList and subscribe to the ListChanged event.

Comment: if I am not wrong, you are asking 2 questions right? 1. How to perform DML operation at time of item remove from listview. 2. How to do cleanup at time of item remove from listview.

Comment: to preform special operations on list collection change you can check this thread : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419419/observablecollectiont-collectionchanged-event`